# Is there a formalism on EM waves that uses only coordinate free calculations?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

This book for example:

> *Theory of Electromagnetic Waves: A Coordinate-free Approach*, by Hollis C. Chen (McGraw-Hill, 1983); [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070106886),

only I can't find it online without a registration.

In general, derivations and calculations should avoid coordinate systems and nonnatural frames or specific basis. Instead coordinate free vector algebra, geometric algebra, differential geometry, etc., should be used.

Comment: Please, link to the article. Some of us can read it and guide you to alternative  sources

Comment: I'm not very familiar with differential geometry, but MTW's *Gravitation* contains a chapter on EM using differential forms, including a section on radiation.

Comment: The amazon link is broken. The URL looks correct in the source code of the answer, but the link is getting munged by SE to point to something on rads.stackoverflow.com, and that URL is broken.

Comment: Are you satisfied with a treatment in abstract index notation (which is coordinate-free, although many people don't realize it), or do you specifically want one in "mathematician notation," without any indices?

Comment: Well , its not so important how you do it( although i like electrodynamics as the curvature of the line bundle) and i would like a clear mathematical notation, but most important thing is to be able to make sense of actual physics directly without having to chose a specific basis of sections or coordinate charts.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to avoid coordinates is through differential geometry, in particular the use of *differential forms*. In fact using differential forms you can define the EM tensor as $$F=dA$$ which indeed in components is $$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu \qquad.$$ In that way you get all Maxwell equations without referring to coordinates.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field

Comment: I know that f is dA, and differential forms equations, but i dont know how to manipulate and use them without writting them in component form.( i dont want to know the component form)

Comment: Iv read baez's gauge fields knots and gravity which is really awesome, up untill he decides its too abstract to continue being coordinate free.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I've never seen something beyond that, then I use coordinates...